# regex to filter sentences based on word length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex to match strings where the length of each word is less than some value.

E.g., if the value is `6`, the regex should match: `"this is a test string"` and not `"this is another test string"`, because the length of "another" is greater than 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?:\b\S{1,5}\b\s*)+$
```

**explanation:**

```
^           : start of string
(?:         : start of non capture group
  \b        : word boundary
  \S{1,5}   : one to five non space char
  \b        : word boundary
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
)+          : end of group one or more times
$           : end of string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^\w{1,5}(\s+\w{1,5})*$
```

this should match strings of one or more words of length up to 5

at least in languages in which the {n,m} syntax is allowed, like Java or Perl

Comment: You should anchor this the the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax of the regular expression you're looking for depends on the language you're using, however this is very possible. The following example is in Python:

```
import re

def matchStringLength(value, string):
  pattern = re.compile('([A-z]{1,%s} )+' % value)
  return pattern.match(string) != None
```

This should be enough to let you develop a method which meets your requirements fully, the above will fail for strings with numbers, special characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\s]{5,}` should do the trick! It will count any other char than spaces, though, so commas etc will be included unless you add them to the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a negative lookahead

```
^(?!.*\b\w{7,}\b).+$
```

See and test it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vmgn)

Here the approach is a different one, basically I accept everything with the `^.+$` part (at least one character because of the `+`, change it to `*` if you would like to accept the empty string also).

Then I add an assertion to the expression `(?!.*\b\w{7,}\b)`. This does not match a character but it checks if the assertion is true. This means here, in the whole string there is no part with 7 or more word characters in a row.

`(?!...)` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`\w` a word character, depends on your language, at least a-zA-Z and _ . In some languages also all Unicode characters that are a letter or a digit are included in `\w`. See here for [character classes on regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), i.e. the change from a word character to a non word character or the other way round.